# How to config spark.io.compression.codec=lzf in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

How to config  spark.io.compression.codec=lzf in Spark?

Usually, I use spark-submit to run our driver class like below

> ./spark-submit --master spark://testserver:7077  --class
>   com.spark.test.SparkTest  --conf "**spark.io.compression.codec=lzf**" 
>   /tmp/test/target/test.jar.

So I can set spark.io.compression.codec=lzf in the command. But if I don't want to use spark-submit to run our driver class. I want to run in a spark-job-server. How to config in spark-job-server ?thanks
I tried to set it in env variables. But it doesn't work. I also tried below. Still not work.

```
sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://testserver:7077").setAppName("Javasparksqltest").
set("spark.executor.memory", "8g").set("spark.io.compression.codec", "lzf");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass that option to `spark-submit`, *or* `spark-shell` by putting it in the `conf/spark-defaults.conf` associated to it. The details are in the [configuration section of the doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties).

For the `spark-jobserver`, you configure a given context, especially if it is being sent as a context implicitly created from a job. There are several ways to do so (the gist of it being that settings are hierarchized under spark.context-settings), but the "Context configuration" of the `Readme.md` details how to do it:

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I mean I don't use the spark-submit. Now I use the spark-job-server. there is no spark-submit in the spark-job-server.

Comment: !? You mean [this spark-jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) ? Don't you think you might have wanted to indicate that in the original question ?

Comment: sorry for confuse you. I have edit accordingly. do you know how to config?

Comment: Does the spark job server support the java application? I found that in spark job-server, job class need to extends the class SparkJob. I tried to use it in java. But I found that the SparkContext in SparkJob class but in java, it it JavaSparkContext. Can I use SparkContext in Java class

Comment: That's a completely different question, as [you noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981057/how-to-use-spark-job-server-for-java-project). I've answered the one you asked here the best I can.

Answer (score 0):

Use complete class name "org.apache.spark.io.LZFCompressionCodec" instead of "lzf"